# Vue, Vuetify, обработка данных со слота с ограниченной областью видимости

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

```
<template>
<v-row>
    <v-col cols="auto">
        <v-dialog
            transition="dialog-top-transition"
            width="auto"
        >
            <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
                <v-btn
                    color="#465af7"
                    v-bind="props"
                    class="ml-3"
                    size="large"
                >Добавить заметку</v-btn>
            </template>
            <template v-slot:default="{isActive}">
                <v-card>
                    <v-toolbar
                        color="#7858d7"
                        title="Добавьте заметку"
                    ></v-toolbar>
                    <v-card-text>
                        <NoteForm
                            @changeActive="setActive"
                        />
                    </v-card-text>
                    <v-card-actions class="justify-end">
                        <v-btn
                            variant="text"
                            @click="isActive.value = true"
                        >Закрыть</v-btn>
                    </v-card-actions>
                </v-card>
            </template>
        </v-dialog>
    </v-col>
</v-row>
</template>
```

В строке

```
template v-slot:default="{isActive}"
```

я получаю `isActive`, там же в шаблоне я могу взаимодействовать с этой переменной `isActive`, например, при клике делать `@click="isActive.value = true"`.

Вопрос: как получить эту переменную `isActive` не в шаблоне компонента, а в его функции `setup`?